# append linked list program crash

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on manipulating linked lists, and my code for append is causing my program to crash

```
Node* append( int x, Node* p ) { 

   Node *q=new Node;

  if(p==nullptr) {
    p->next=q;
    q->value=x;
 }

  while (p!=nullptr) {
     p=p->next;
  }
  //arrived at NULL ptr
    p->next=q;
   q->value=x;
   q->next=nullptr;

   return q;
}
```

Comment: I think this is wrongly tagged with node.js :P

Answer (score 1):

It seem's like you're de-referencing a `nullptr` here ?

```
if(p==nullptr) {
   p->next=q;
   ...
}
```